# How to establish connection between Java Program and Database without using IDE/ External Tools?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ide

I want to write a Java Program for Establishing Connection between Java Program and Database, but I don't want to use any IDE like Netbeans, Eclipse, Visual Studio, XAMP, etc. I have jar files for Driver of required DBMS.

```html
public class JDBCDemo
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    try
    {
          /**
       * Steps for Establishing Connection between Java Application and Database
       */

      //1. Load and Reginster Driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //2. Establish a connection between Java Application and Database
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practicals", "root", "root123");

      //3. Create Statement Object
      Statement st = con.createStatement();

      //4. Send and Execute SQL queries
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tushar");

      //5. Process the result from ResultSet object
      while(rs.next())
      {
         System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
      }

      //6. Close the Connection           
      con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println(e.toString().trim());
    }
  }
}
```

It is showing error
***java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver***

How to Establish connection ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the mysql driver jar in the classpath before you run the program.

There are various ways to do so.

1. javac -cp "JAR_PATH" ClassName.java
   java -cp "JAR_PATH" ClassName
2. Add the jar file in C:\Program Files\Java\\jre\lib\ext
3. set classpath=PATH_TO_JAR;

Comment: Thanks for answer,                                                                                                     Option1 shows following error                                                        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver                                                                                      Option3 is also not working                                                                                                                   As I am using Ubuntu there is no such directory  C:\Program Files\

Comment: @AKASHGUDADHE Dude. Request you to use corresponding commands for unix.

Answer (score 0):

```
colon(:) is compulsory after jar file name
```

> Compilling Program

*javac -cp  mysql-connector.jar:  ProgramFileName.java*

**javac -cp  mysql-connector.jar:  JDBCDemo.java**

> Running Program

*java -cp mysql-connector.jar: ProgramFileName*

**java -cp mysql-connector.jar: JDBCDemo**

**Note:-** Simillar can be applied while using other jar files for performing other operations.

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e2KT.png)